# Entity Framework not generating correct query

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and this is probably something very straightforward. I'm having a problem whereby the query it is generating in my repository is not the expected query and therefore it returns no results from the `Users table`. I have the following code that is supposed to filter the collection of users by username and password:

```
var user = _userRepository.Users.Where(u => u.Username == request.Username && u.Password == request.Password).FirstOrDefault();
```

But the resultant query is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Username] AS [Username], 
[Extent1].[Password] AS [Password]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Admin',N'User')
```

So it doesn't find any results. Also it appears to be filtering on a column called `[Discriminator]` but the User object type doesn't have any inheritance, just a User class.

What am I missing to make it generate the expected queries? eg SQL query that simply filters on username and password.

Comment: the discriminator column could be the result of some inheritance mapping. why the where and top clause are missing I can't tell, probably some mistake in the repository (i.e. not returning preparing IQueryables).

Comment: How does `_userRepository.Users` look like? What type is it? Sounds like it returns all used from DB who are `Admin` or `User`. And then you `Where` is applied to in-memory collection.